# Avoid required=true constraint of an input field when changing selection in dropdown

Tags: validation, jsf, selectonemenu

I have a dropdown and a text field next to it. Based on value selected in dropdown I am changing the type of text field, like change it to date, integer, text. Those text fields have required attribute set to true.

So when I select a different value in dropdown, I can change the type of text field but I also get a required error message on the text field. How can I avoid this?

I am using JSF 1.2.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="SelectField"  
    value="#{logSearchBean.searchType}"    
    onchange="this.form.submit();"
    valueChangeListener="#{logSearchBean.searchValueType}" >
    <f:selectItems  value="#{logSearchBean.columnDesc}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:inputText id="SearchText"
    value="#{logSearchBean.searchValue}"
    required="true"
    requiredMessage="Please provide value to Search for"
    rendered="#{logSearchBean.searchValueEditor eq 'SearchText'}"/>

<t:inputDate id="SearchDate"
    value="#{logSearchBean.searchValueDate}"
    popupCalendar="true"
    required="true"
    requiredMessage="Please provide value to Search for"
    rendered="#{logSearchBean.searchValueEditor eq 'SearchDate'}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Add `immediate="true"` to the dropdown.

   ```
   <h:selectOneMenu immediate="true">
   ```

   This will cause the `valueChangeListener` method being invoked during apply request values phase instead of the validations phase. Thus, it will be invoked one phase earlier than usual and all other input fields without `immediate="true"` aren't processed yet at that point.
2. In the `valueChangeListener` method associated with the dropdown, call [`FacesContext#renderResponse()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#renderResponse%28%29).

   ```
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
   ```

   This will instruct JSF to bypass all remaining phases until the render response phase. Thus, the other input fields without `immediate="true"` won't be processed anymore.